# Sqlite cannot read an encrypted password in laravel

Tags: sqlite, laravel-5

I'm using laravel and sqlite database but i have a problem when i try to login into my app. It seems like sqlite cannot read my encrypt user password, because all data processes are work well except that one.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: This description of the problem is far too vague.  You're going to have to add a *lot* more detail of what you're doing to expect an answer.

Comment: can sqlite database read decrypted password for login case, sir?

Comment: I suspect your problem is more to do with laravel than sqlite3.  SQLite3 itself has no concept of a "login password".  Unfortunately, I have no experience with laravel, so I cannot help you with that.  What I really want to emphasize here is that it is important that you give *precise* details on what you are attempting to do and what is going wrong if you can expect to get an answer.

Comment: it already worked finaly, you're right. my problem is with my laravel project :).